# What is the best source of news from SharePoint world?

Tags: newsletter

I am looking for site/resource where I can subscribe to SharePoint news and receive weekly/monthly digest of hottest and latest news.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for old-school IT geezers like me, email still better than yammer, even with digest stuff :)
so my preference is one gathered by our local SP community: http://tinyletter.com/BelarusSharePoint/letters/belarus-sharepoint-community-newsletter-25-3

PS especially I like cats bonus there ;)

Comment: Thank Ivan. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, this newsletter is awesome, I've been a subscriber for the last 5 months, and the content is great.

Answer (score 9):

Well according to me, it is yammer O365 network. There you will receive latest updates. It has many dedicated groups for sharepoint also. You might want to try it.

[Yammer](https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/)

Comment: you beat me to this :-)

Comment: hahaha <grin>. It is actually good :)

Answer (score 4):

You can sign-up for newsletters from these two sites.

- http://sharepointpromag.com/
- http://www.sharepointreviews.com/ (this one is more about vendor offering in SP area)

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint Community at http://sharepoint-community.net/ is a great resource as well.